# How to draw a line from the point to X axis, in the JavaFX ScatterChart?

Tags: java, charts, javafx, javafx-8

Now I am work with JavaFX ScatterChart and I need to draw a line from the point of data to X axis, as I show in the image below.

[image]

Thak you for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to create a custom chart and add the lines as custom nodes. This is very similar to the marker lines in the answer to the [Adding a line in a JavaFX chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232931/adding-a-line-in-a-javafx-chart/24403761#24403761) question.